# How can I write positive/negative tests for C++ overload resolution and SFINAE?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, sfinae, overload-resolution

I'm currently designing some functions that make use of SFINAE to control overload resolution. This is easy to get wrong, so I'd like to be able to write both positive and negative tests for what the API can be called with. For example:

```cpp
// A templated function that should only be used via type deduction. (We
// don't want to let users to set template arguments explicitly in order
// to reserve the right to change them. They are not a public API.)
template <
    int&... ExplicitArgumentBarrier,
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same_v<T, int>>>
void AcceptVector(std::vector<T>);

// We should be able to feed the function most vectors.
static_assert(kCanCallAcceptVector<std::vector<double>>);
static_assert(kCanCallAcceptVector<std::vector<std::string>>);

// But not vector<int>.
static_assert(!kCanCallAcceptVector<std::vector<int>>);
```

It feels like I should be able to do this with `std::is_invocable_v`, but that requires us to explicitly name the object being called, which requires providing template arguments and which assumes something about the overload set. Instead I literally want to test overload resolution: regardless of how many overloads for `AcceptVector` there are and what their template arguments look like, is a call site spelled `AcceptVector` that provides a particular type as argument valid?

What's the best way to do this? Here is what I've come up with:

```cpp
#define DEFINE_CAN_CALL_VARIABLE(namespace_name, function_name)           \
  template <typename... Args>                                             \
  struct internal_CanCall##function_name final {                          \
   private:                                                               \
    struct Functor {                                                      \
      template <typename... U,                                            \
                typename = decltype(::namespace_name ::function_name(     \
                    std::declval<U>()...))>                               \
      void operator()(U&&... args);                                       \
    };                                                                    \
                                                                          \
   public:                                                                \
    static constexpr bool kValue = std::is_invocable_v<Functor, Args...>; \
  };                                                                      \
                                                                          \
  template <typename... Args>                                             \
  inline constexpr bool kCanCall##function_name =                         \
      internal_CanCall##function_name<Args...>::kValue;

DEFINE_CAN_CALL_VARIABLE(my::project, AcceptVector);
```

The idea is to define a functor that we *can* name for `std::is_invocable_v`, and then lean on overload resolution in that functor. But there are some downsides:

- I have to package it into a macro in order to make it reusable without having the same problem as `std::is_invocable_v` over again.
- I need to have the user provide the namespace as a macro argument in order to avoid problems due to argument-dependent lookup. (Although I said I'm interested in any call spelled `AcceptVector`, I guess I really mean any call spelled `AcceptVector` that resolves to an `AcceptVector` function in my project's namespace.)
- I'm not 100% sure I haven't missed other edge cases.

Does it seem like this is correct? Is there a less awful way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just write unit tests instead of `static_assert`? Then you can actually test if the function calls work as intended. Then you can just verify by trying `std::is_invocable` without writing all of that macro or wrapping things in classes. `static_assert` isn't exactly made for the tests you use it for.

Comment: `static_assert` is necessary for the _negative_ tests as far as I can tell. I can't "just" write a test that calls the function with a type it doesn't support unless I have a whole harness that tests that compilation fails, which is cumbersome and messy.

Comment: nope. What do you think `std::invocable` does? It compile time tests whether or not something is invocable or not and generates a boolean. You just compare the answer in the unit test. In the answer below a fellow recommended a `concept` - which is equivalent to a `type_trait`.

Comment: @ALX23z I mean, you _could_ have unit tests that do `CHECK_FALSE(some_trait_v<T>);` instead of `static_assert(!some_trait_t<T>);` But how you choose to check your trait in your unit test doesn't really answer the question of how to write the trait to begin with.

Comment: @Barry that's why it is in comment instead of an answer. I referred only to the improper practice of `static_assert` - as it doesn't help at all. I could check out how to implement proper `std::is_invocable` for template functions. But it seems that you've added reference to experimental `is_detected` already that solves the case equivalently to the concept.

Comment: @ALX23z There is nothing "improper" about `static_assert`.

Comment: @Barry depends on usage. Putting a general `static_assert` tests in header files is wasteful. At least put them into .cpp so that not every translation unit has to verify them upon compilation. And `static_assert` is in no way helps to figure out if something compiles or not as opposed to OPs comment. One needs SFINAE based type traits or equivalent to achieve that. Basically, `static_assert` doesn't really adds anything useful to achieve OPs goal. Unit tests do it way better.

Comment: I have no idea why you're arguing about this. `static_assert` in the test catches the issue at compile time, which may or may not be preferable to catching it later, at runtime. (There are positives and negatives to each.) They both do what I need here; this is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this C++20, the better approach is to write a concept:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
concept canAcceptVector = requires (Args(*args)()...) {
    AcceptVector(args()...);
};
```

Which you can then test:

```cpp
// We should be able to feed the function most vectors.
static_assert(canAcceptVector<std::vector<double>>);
static_assert(canAcceptVector<std::vector<std::string>>);

// But not vector<int>.
static_assert(!canAcceptVector<std::vector<int>>);
```

---

The odd formulation with the function pointer is to ensure that `canAcceptVector<int>`, `canAcceptVector<int&>`, and `canAcceptVector<int&&>` try to call `AcceptVector` with a prvalue, lvalue, and xvalue respectively. Probably not super important in this case, but I find it slightly less unwieldy than dealing with `std::forward` and plus it correctly deals with prvalues.

---

The best C++17 approach for this problem is the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), which requires an extra step over concepts:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
using AcceptVector_t = decltype(AcceptVector(std::declval<Args>()...));

template <typename... Args>
inline constexpr bool canAcceptVector = is_detected_v<AcceptVector_t, Args...>;
```

Which you can `static_assert` in the same way as above.

Comment: This is super interesting, thanks. I tagged `c++20` because I was interested if there was something there that would help (it turns out there is!), but unfortunately I'm still stuck on C++17 for now. Is there a C++17-compatible solution you can think of?

Comment: @jacobsa Added a C++17 answer.

Comment: @Barry the problem with the `concept` and the `is_detectible`. Is that one cannot properly test every type of functions. Say, can it properly work for `std::make_unique` where one has to explicitly write the first template argument?

Comment: @Barry: nice, thanks; I hadn't heard of `std::experimental::is_detected`. That's pretty much what I need! Except do you understand how it interacts with ADL? The `decltype` expression in `AcceptVector_t` is going to be subject to ADL, right?

Comment: @ALX23z: this question is specifically about checking functions where it's forbidden to specify the template arguments explicitly.